# combine multiple xml into one

Tags: php, xml, arrays, parsing, xml-parsing

Hi i am parsing one xml feed into an array and its working fine for me but till now i have only one xml feed but now i am bit of stuck at one point because i need to combine multiple xml into one and then parse whole xml into an array. here i am providing some example code what actual i want.

**XML1**

```
<JobRecords>
    <JobRecord>
        <Brand>Corporate1</Brand>
        <WorkTypes>
            <WorkTypeRecord>
                <Title>Permanent1</Title>
            </WorkTypeRecord>
        </WorkTypes>
    </JobRecord>
</JobRecords>
```

**XML2**

```
<JobRecords>
    <JobRecord>
        <Brand>Corporate2</Brand>
        <WorkTypes>
            <WorkTypeRecord>
                <Title>Permanent2</Title>
            </WorkTypeRecord>
        </WorkTypes>
    </JobRecord>
</JobRecords>
```

**XML3**

```
<JobRecords>
    <JobRecord>
        <Brand>Corporate3</Brand>
        <WorkTypes>
            <WorkTypeRecord>
                <Title>Permanent3</Title>
            </WorkTypeRecord>
        </WorkTypes>
    </JobRecord>
</JobRecords>
```

**Combine XML that i want as output**

```
<JobRecords>
    <JobRecord>
        <Brand>Corporate1</Brand>
        <WorkTypes>
            <WorkTypeRecord>
                <Title>Permanent1</Title>
            </WorkTypeRecord>
        </WorkTypes>
    </JobRecord>
    <JobRecord>
        <Brand>Corporate2</Brand>
        <WorkTypes>
            <WorkTypeRecord>
                <Title>Permanent2</Title>
            </WorkTypeRecord>
        </WorkTypes>
    </JobRecord>
    <JobRecord>
        <Brand>Corporate3</Brand>
        <WorkTypes>
            <WorkTypeRecord>
                <Title>Permanent3</Title>
            </WorkTypeRecord>
        </WorkTypes>
    </JobRecord>
</JobRecords>
```

So far i have tried below code and it's work for me but take too much time for generate combine output.xml. so is there any other way to achieve this with better solution.

```
function simplexml_merge(SimpleXMLElement &$xml1, SimpleXMLElement $xml2) {
        // convert SimpleXML objects into DOM ones
        $dom1 = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $dom2 = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

        $dom1->loadXML($xml1->asXML());
        $dom2->loadXML($xml2->asXML());
        // pull all child elements of second XML
        $xpath = new domXPath($dom2);
        $xpathQuery = $xpath->query('/*/*');
        for ($i = 0; $i < $xpathQuery->length; $i++) {
            // and pump them into first one
            $dom1->documentElement->appendChild(
                $dom1->importNode($xpathQuery->item($i), true));
        }
        $xml1 = simplexml_import_dom($dom1);
    }

    $xml1 = simplexml_load_file("xml1.xml", 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $xml2 = simplexml_load_file("xml2.xml", 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    simplexml_merge($xml1, $xml2);
    $xml1->asXml('output.xml');
```

Please advise me what is the best way to achieve this.
Thanks in advance and much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Dh, good start! You could look into `simplexml` or `DOM` and try some code. If you need help, edit your question, show what you've tried and point out specifically what you need.

Comment: @michi i have updated my question with the code that i have tried so far please take look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use DOM, not SimpleXML. I added the XML to an array, here. In real code that might be a list of filenames and DOMDocument::load() would be used, not DOMdocument::loadXml().

```
$addXml = array();
$addXml[] = '<JobRecords>
    <JobRecord>
        <Brand>Corporate1</Brand>
        <WorkTypes>
            <WorkTypeRecord>
                <Title>Permanent1</Title>
            </WorkTypeRecord>
        </WorkTypes>
    </JobRecord>
</JobRecords>';
$addXml[] = '<JobRecords>
    <JobRecord>
        <Brand>Corporate2</Brand>
        <WorkTypes>
            <WorkTypeRecord>
                <Title>Permanent2</Title>
            </WorkTypeRecord>
        </WorkTypes>
    </JobRecord>
</JobRecords>';

// create a new document
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// and add the root element
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('JobRecords'));

// for each document/xml to add
foreach ($addXml as $xml) {
  // create a dom
  $addDom = new DOMDocument();
  // load the xml
  $addDom->loadXml($xml);
  // if here is a root node in the loaded xml
  if ($addDom->documentElement) {
    // for each child of the loaded root node
    foreach ($addDom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
      // append to the result dom
      $dom->documentElement->appendChild(
        // after importing the child to the result dom
        $dom->importNode($node, TRUE)
      );
    }
  }
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

About the same using a list of filenames/urls:

```
$files= array(
  'xml1.xml',
  'xml2.xml'
);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('JobRecords'));

foreach ($files as $filename) {
  $addDom = new DOMDocument();
  $addDom->load($filename);
  if ($addDom->documentElement) {
    foreach ($addDom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
      $dom->documentElement->appendChild(
        $dom->importNode($node, TRUE)
      );
    }
  }
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Comment: Hi how can i add the XML to an array because i am having feed url and xml data load from that url.

Comment: i got the solution of my previous comment.