# Replace specific node value in xml using php

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xml-parsing

Hi i am parsing multiple xml feed and combine into one and its working fine for me but now i am bit of stuck at one point because i need to add some prefix into specific node value i mean i need to change the value of that node. here i am providing some example code what actual i want.

**XML**

```
<JobRecords>
    <JobRecord>
        <Brand>Corporate1</Brand>
        <JobId>45982</JobId>
        <WorkTypes>
            <WorkTypeRecord>
                <Title>Permanent1</Title>
            </WorkTypeRecord>
        </WorkTypes>
    </JobRecord>
    <JobRecord>
        <Brand>Corporate2</Brand>
        <JobId>45983</JobId>
        <WorkTypes>
            <WorkTypeRecord>
                <Title>Permanent2</Title>
            </WorkTypeRecord>
        </WorkTypes>
    </JobRecord>
    <JobRecord>
        <Brand>Corporate3</Brand>
        <JobId>45984</JobId>
        <WorkTypes>
            <WorkTypeRecord>
                <Title>Permanent3</Title>
            </WorkTypeRecord>
        </WorkTypes>
    </JobRecord>
</JobRecords>
```

In the above xml i want to append the prefix like this `<JobId>0-45984</JobId>`

Here is the **php code** which combine different xml feed into one give out put as above.

```
<?php 
    $feed1 = "data1.xml";
    $feed2 = "data2.xml"; 
    $feed3 = "data3.xml";

    $xml1 = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $xml1->load($feed1);

    $xml2 = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $xml2->load($feed2);

    $xml3 = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $xml3->load($feed3);

    $addXml = array();
    $addXml[] = $xml1->saveXML();
    $addXml[] = $xml2->saveXML();
    $addXml[] = $xml3->saveXML();

    // create a new document
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('JobRecords'));

    foreach ($addXml as $xml) {
      $addDom = new DOMDocument();
      $addDom->loadXml($xml);
      if ($addDom->documentElement) {
        foreach ($addDom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
          $dom->documentElement->appendChild(
            $dom->importNode($node, TRUE)
          );
        }
      }
    }

    $xmlFinal = $dom->saveXml();
    echo $xmlFinal;
?>
```

I have tried so far but didn't succeed Please advise me how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance and much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could iterate from root and check and replace the node like following. Here `$xmlData` holds the string of your xml.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlData);
foreach ($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
//print_r($node);
if($node->nodeType==1){
   $OldJobId = $node->getElementsByTagName('JobId')->Item(0);
   $newelement = $dom->createElement('JobId','0-'.$OldJobId->nodeValue); 
    $OldJobId->parentNode->replaceChild($newelement, $OldJobId);
 }
}
$str = $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
echo $str;
```

You can find working demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c5a59a6804c8e229931c45a2c07b655f97e9809)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you don't load the xml feed directly inside the loop, like in the second example of the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372216/combine-multiple-xml-into-one).

After importing the 'JobRecord' element into the target, document, you have to find it JobId child and modify it's nodeValue property

```
$files= array(
  'xml1.xml',
  'xml2.xml',
  'xml3.xml'
  // ... more xmls
);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('JobRecords'));
// get an xpath object
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// $index variable for later use
foreach ($files as $index => $filename) {
  $addDom = new DOMDocument();
  $addDom->load($filename);
  if ($addDom->documentElement) {
    foreach ($addDom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
      $dom->documentElement->appendChild(
        $record = $dom->importNode($node, TRUE)
      );
      // find the jobId child elements (should be only one)
      $jobIds = $xpath->evaluate('./JobId', $record);
      foreach ($jobIds as $jobId) {
        // prefix the value with the index
        $jobId->nodeValue = $index.'-'.$jobId->nodeValue;
      }
    }
  }
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Comment: Nothing happens with this answer can you please take a look again in your answer.

Comment: Hi i have tried above code but nothing happens with the above code man. value of jobId does not changed at all.

Comment: It works just fine. I tested it locally. https://eval.in/78610 (changed to use xml texts).

Comment: If you check the example, you should see the difference. Use DOMDocument::loadXml() to load xml strings and DOMDocument::load() to load xml files.