# How to update an xml file on filesystem conditionally - PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, laravel-5

I have the xml file called `fonts.xml` located on my filesystem.

**Goal:**

I want to update the attribute `<status>` where `name` is "Aclonica" but I don't know how to do it conditionally.

**XML:**

```
<fonts>
  <font>
   <name>Aclonica</name>
   <category>Aclonica</category>
   <variants>100,bold</variants>
   <status>active</status>
  </font>
  <font>
   <name>Azeebe</name>
   <category>Sans-serif</category>
   <variants>100,bold,italic</variants>
   <status>active</status>
  </font>
</fonts>
```

Comment: you can refer this solution for xml update:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540592/replace-specific-node-value-in-xml-using-php

Comment: https://eval.in/598922

Comment: so did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `DOMDocument` class. This way you select data using normal `if` condition:

**solution:**

```
$a = $_POST['font']; // here value 'Aclonica' is assigned to $a
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->load('c:/xampp/htdocs/cms/public/fonts/font.xml');

foreach ($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {

    // print_r($node); // >> uncomment for debug purposes

    if($node->nodeType == 1) {
       $name = $node->getElementsByTagName('name')->Item(0);

       if($name->nodeValue == $a) { // >> IMPORTANT: here is the condition you need

         $OldJobId = $node->getElementsByTagName('status')->Item(0);

         if($OldJobId->nodeValue == 'active') {

          $newelement = $dom->createElement('status','inactive'); 

          $OldJobId->parentNode->replaceChild($newelement, $OldJobId);
         }else{

          $newelement = $dom->createElement('status','active'); 
          $OldJobId->parentNode->replaceChild($newelement, $OldJobId);
         }
       }
     }
}

$dom->save("c:/xampp/htdocs/cms/public/fonts/font.xml");
```